# CTP5 vs release 4.1 EF many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

This code doesn't work. What is wrong? OnModelCreating doesnt't effect any result? Because I can not see "ProductCategories" table in my Database.

```
    public class GoldContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Prouct> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //HACK:4.1 modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new DecimalPrecisionAttributeConvention());
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany<Category>(m => m.Categories)
            .WithMany().Map(m => 
                m.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
                .MapRightKey("CategoryId")
                .ToTable("ProductCategories"));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

//product and category classes look like this.

    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Is there a chance that you are looking the wrong database and/or context? Any error messages?

Comment: Hi, I tried to give more info. There is no any error message. all are ok! but there is no datatable as "ProductCategories" promissed for us.

Comment: That's weird, I've added your entities/mappings to a project and everything worked as expected (including the `ProductCategories` table.

Comment: By the way, you should write `.WithMany(c => c.Products)`. Otherwise EF won't assume that `Category.Products` belongs to your many-to-many relationship and creates instead a second one-to-many relationship between `Category` and `Product`. `Category.Products` would belong to that relationship. But that's only a side note, it's not the source of your current problem.

Comment: Slauma, yes you are absolutely right. I have been wrote same map for category also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've tried in a console application and works as expected :

```
namespace Q7122388
{
    #region Imports

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;

    #endregion

    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasMany<Category>(m => m.Categories)
                .WithMany().Map(m =>
                    m.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
                    .MapRightKey("CategoryId")
                    .ToTable("ProductCategories"));
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DatabaseContext>());
            using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
                context.Database.Initialize(true);
        }
    }
}
```